# Combining 2 tables in SQL Server different Data in each table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got two tables I want to Join or combine together. Is this possible? I've tried using different Joins without success. Any help would be great. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried so far?  As you're new, [please check out how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It seems this is a Full Outer Join situation.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: If you were helping , wouldn't you want to know what's already been tried?

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, my current code is similar to the below stated by satishcse. SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*

FROM Table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 TABLE1
ON Table1.ID = Table2.IDso this is basically the query I'm running that I've gotten to work. some of the columns are the same on both tables so I have to create aliases for the duplicates, but was hoping to get the records missing from table 1 or vice versa into the same columns instead of an alias

Answer (score 1):

`Full Outer Join` would be perfect for this scenario. Try like below:

```
Select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.Name = t1.Name
```

Although I have doubt on your statement "*I've tried using different Joins without success*".